# How to animate a view while component is on being mounted in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have gone through the lifecycle, but I don't yet find the solution for this question, As for my knowledge all you can animate any view only after a component is mounted, I still wonder if there any way to animate a view before/while the component is loading?

Comment: thanks for your information?@Auticcat

Comment: Should check this library https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-motion

Answer (score 0):

If the component is not yet mounted you can not animate any view from that component because they do not yet exist. I hope this helps.